# Cookies expiration time format

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I created DB from google chrome's Cookies file and one of the columns in the `cookies` table is `expires_utc`. The format of the column is like - 13169399213145330, which is more like unix time. But when i'm trying to use unix time converter, it gives wrong values.

So, what format is that and how i can convert it to actually unix time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, after long researches on this topic, here is the solution:

- Chrome's cookies timestap's epoch starts 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z (Why? Because.)

So, it's 11644473600 seconds before the UNIX epoch. To convert chrome's timestamp to UNIX, you need to:

1. Devide the actual timestamp (in my case it's `expires_utc` column in `cookies` table) by 1000000 // And someone should explain my why.
2. Subtract 11644473600
3. DONE! Now you got UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for this!
About the divide by 1.000.000 - it's probably because it is in milliseconds

Comment: actually it's microseconds und by dividing it by 1M you get seconds.

Comment: Here's more info on the how and why of the 1601/1/1, it's not random :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849717/what-is-the-significance-of-january-1-1601