# What format Google Chrome using for cookies expire?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cookiestore

If i export cookie from Chrome with "EditThisCookie" extension i see something like this:

```
{
    "domain": ".youtube.com",
    "expirationDate": 1599457462,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "GA1.2.1666271553.1536385462",
    "id": 1
}
```

and if i open Cookie databses (file Cookies in app folder) with DBExplorer, i see this:

```
expires_utc: 13243931062000000
```

How 13243931062000000 became 1599457462?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expires_utc` is microseconds from 1601-01-01T00:00:00Z.

While `expirationDate` appears to be in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

You can find more information about `expires_utc` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518199/cookies-expiration-time-format).

Comment: I saw that article. This is the best part: "Devide the actual timestamp (in my case it's expires_utc column in cookies table) by 1000000 // And someone should explain my why." Yes, you are right, (13243931062000000  / 1000000) - 11644473600 = 1599457462